# Plotting shinyTable data

Tags: r, markdown, shiny

I'm trying to embed a editable shiny table into a rmarkdown file. After interactively input the table my code must plot the content of the table along with other data from my workspace.

I've succeeded in the first step, I've managed to input the table using the shinyTable package. But I'm stuck trying to create the plot. I dont know how to call the table values so I can use them in other sections of my code.

I want to be able to call the generated table outside the shinyApp(.) block (see code below).

Code sample

````html
---
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

#This is a R Markdown file

```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(shinyTable)
shinyApp(
server = function(input, output,session) {
  cachedTbl <- NULL
  output$tbl <- renderHtable({
    if (is.null(input$tbl)){
      rows <- 5
      tbl <- data.frame(list(num1=1:rows, 
                             num2=(1:rows)*20,
                             letter=LETTERS[1:(rows)]))
      rownames(tbl) <- LETTERS[2:(rows+1)]      
      cachedTbl <<- tbl      
      return(tbl)
    } else{
      tbl <- input$tbl
      cachedTbl <<- tbl
      return(tbl)
    }
  })  
},  
ui = fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    htable("tbl", colHeaders="provided")
  )
)
)
renderText({
  paste(is.null(input$tbl))   ## This line returns "TRUE"
  })
```
````

Comment: In a Shiny app you would use `input$tbl` assuming tbl was the id you used to create the table. Does that not work? You are more likely to get help if you can provide an example of what you tried.

Comment: I've edited the original post. What Im trying to accomplish is to actully use the input$tbl in other sections of my rmarkdown code, I have more than one Shiny app in the markdown file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a reactive value, either with reactiveValues or makeReactiveBinding (http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/)

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
cachedTbl <<- 0
makeReactiveBinding("cachedTbl")

library(shinyTable)
shinyApp(
server = function(input, output,session) {
  # cachedTbl <- NULL
  output$tbl <- renderHtable({
    if (is.null(input$tbl)){
      rows <- 5
      tbl <- data.frame(list(num1=1:rows, 
                             num2=(1:rows)*20,
                             letter=LETTERS[1:(rows)]))
      rownames(tbl) <- LETTERS[2:(rows+1)]      
      cachedTbl <<- tbl      
      return(tbl)
    } else{
      tbl <- input$tbl
      cachedTbl <<- tbl
      return(tbl)
    }
  })  
},  
ui = fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    htable("tbl", colHeaders="provided")
  )
)
)
renderText({
  # paste(is.null(input$tbl))   ## This line returns "TRUE"
  cachedTbl[[2]]
})
```
````